# Understanding the conversion of date and time to specific timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a date and time in api response. Which I need to convert in user timezone.

[image: start_date_time]

```
datetime: function (datetime) {
    return moment(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz(timeZone).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
},
```

However, the `start_date_time` are the same as it is in the response. Just the format is changed. If I changed to another timezone it works fine. My timezone is `"Asia/Kolkata"`

How do I let moment know that this date and time doesn't belong to "Asia/Kolkata" and needs to convert it in same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `start_date_time` is UTC time then you must add a `Z` at the end of it:

```js
const start_date_time = "2019-04-20 02:00:00";
const timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
console.log(moment(start_date_time+"Z"));
console.log("Asia/Kolkata date: ", moment(start_date_time+"Z").tz(timeZone).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise you must first specify the timeZone of the `start_date_time` then you can convert it to another timezone:

```js
const start_date_time = moment.tz("2019-04-20 02:00:00", "America/New_York");
console.log(start_date_time.format());

const timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
console.log("Asia/Kolkata date: ", start_date_time.tz(timeZone).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That UTC. How do we know the time is UTC. Does it have a specific format?

Comment: The format of utc date is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`